# grouped loess scores

Tags: r

I've got this data.frame: http://sprunge.us/TMGS, and I'd like to calculate the `loess` of `Intermediate.MAP.Score ~ x`, so I get one curve from the whole dataset. But every group (by `name`) should have the same wight as every other group, I'm not sure what happens if I call `loess` over the whole `data.frame`. Do I need to call it once per group and combine them? If yes, how do I do that?

Comment: Getting one loess for the full dataset is trivial. Where is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can apply the loess to the whole dataset and give the same weight to all groups.

Comment: The solution below does exactly that.

Comment: Nope, that solution creates a loess fit for every group. I'd like one fit for all of the data.

Comment: Please look at the edit and new plot again. It provides a a mean value across groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to average over all of the values in 'loess.fits' produced in my earlier answer to a different question, you will get one answer. If you want to just get a `loess` fit on the entire dataset (which would not fit your "equal weighting" spec at least as I interpret  that phrase), you will get another answer.

This would produce averaged 'yhat' values at the 51 equally spaced data values for 'x' in the range of [0,1]. Because of missing values, it may not be exactly "equally weighted" but only at the extremes. The estimates are dense elsewhere:

```
apply( as.data.frame(loess.fits), 1, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

[image]

Earlier answer:
I would have titled the question "loess scores split by group":

```
plot(dat$x, dat$Intermediate.MAP.Score, col=as.numeric(factor(dat$name)) )
```

If you proceed with `loess(Intermediate.MAP.Score ~ x, data=dat)` you will get an overall average with no distinction among groups. And loess doesn't accept factor or character arguments in its formula. You need to split by 'name' and calculate separately. The other gotcha to avoid is plotting on the default limits which will be driven varying data ranges:

```
loess.fits <- lapply(split(dat, dat$name), function(xdf) { 
              list( yhat=predict( loess(Intermediate.MAP.Score ~ x, 
                                    data=xdf[ complete.cases(
                                            xdf[ , c("Intermediate.MAP.Score", "x") ]
                                                               ), 
                                                 ] ) ,
                                  newdata=data.frame(x=seq(0,1,by=0.02))))})
plot(dat$x, dat$Intermediate.MAP.Score, 
                   col=as.numeric(factor(dat$name)), 
                   ylim=c(0.2,1) )
lapply(loess.fits, function(xdf) { par(new=TRUE); 
                                 # so the plots can be compared to predictions
                                  plot(x= seq(0,1,by=0.02), y=xdf$yhat, 
                                       ylab="", xlab="",
                                       ylim=c(0.2,1), axes=FALSE) })
```

[image]

Comment: Argh, I should have read the question again, I forgot the most important part, sorry.